# CSS - Flex positioning with two separate parent divs

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am attempting to change the positioning I have on my page when in mobile.  I'm approaching this by using `flex positioning`. My issue at the moment is that I have three items that I am trying to position: `one, two and three`. `one and three` share the same parent div `#RightSide` and `two` has it's one div `#LeftSide`. This set up is used for desktop display.

When I'm trying to position my item `two` in `#LeftSide` div as second right under the `one` item under `#RightSide` it does not work. It seems that because each item have separate parent divs that I cannot position `two` over `three` who is in the same div `one`. I've tried going about this by wrapping the entire divs in one div called `mobile-flex` and adding `display:flex` but that did not help.

How can I solve this issue?

Here is a code snippet of my work:

```css
.pull-right {
  float:right;
}

.pull-left {
  float:left;
}


@media (max-width: 400px) {
.pull-right {
  float:none;
}

.pull-left {
  float:none;
}

    #mobile-flex {
        display: flex;
        position: relative;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: space-around;
    }

#RightSide {
         display: flex;
        position: relative;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: space-around;
}

#LeftSide {
        display: flex;
        position: relative;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: space-around;
}
    #one {
        order: 1;
    }

    #two {
        order: 2;
    }

    #three {
        order:3;
    }
    
}
```

```html
<div class='row'>
 <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 pull-right" id="RightSide">
 
 <div id='one'>
  one 
 </div> 
 <div id='three'>
 three
 </div>
 </div>
  <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-xs-12  pull-left" id="LeftSide">
 <div id='two'>
two 
 </div>
</div>
```

My expected outcome result on mobile is to show:

```
one
two
three
```

---

Current display :

```
one
three
two
```

Link to a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zgnpxqLd/4/)

Comment: No where in your markup is a div with an id of `two`. Also, you cannot change the order if they are different parent elements.

Comment: add display:contents to #RightSide and #LeftSide on small screen then you can do it

Comment: @TemaniAfif would I need to have a parent div of `#mobile-flex` in order to do so?

Comment: not really, you can make `.row` your flex container and the order will do the trick